# listener.accept gives error when passed a unique_ptr to sf::TcpSocket

Tags: c++, sfml

I have been trying to make a server for a game I have been developing.
The problem with it was that if someone disconnects, the person that connected last would get disconnected, because of the way I can made the server.

I had asked how to fix this on the sfml forums and received a response saying instead of using `std::vector<sf::TcpSocket> clients` use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::TcpSocket>> clients`.

After changing all the everything to suit this change, I ran into a problem with this code:

```
while (listener.accept(clients[numClients + 1].get()) == sf::Socket::Done)
```

As far as I can tell, this should work, but I somehow managed to f*ck it up and get this error:

```
initial value of reference to non-const must be an ivalue
```

Here is a snippet with just the problem code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <SFML\Network.hpp>

int main()
{
    const int maxClients = 100;
    int numClients = 0;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::TcpSocket>> clients(maxClients);

    sf::TcpListener listener;

    while (listener.accept(clients[numClients + 1].get()) == sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        numClients++;
        std::cout << "new guy connected" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm quite new to sfml and c++ (only about a year of experience), so please write responses that someone like me can understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TcpListener.accept`-Method expects the argument as reference, but you are passing it as a pointer (note, that [std::unique_ptr::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) returns a pointer). You need to dereference the unique pointer:

`listener.accept(*(clients.at(numClients+1)))`

Also you should use the [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)-method to access the members.